# How to separate string using delimiters "( ) { } [ ]"

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I want to split string using "()" "{}" and "[]" these delimiters but I achieved partial.
Below is example, what I want to do. Second example working perfectly but not first one.

eg. 1

```
input: hello(something))split)done

output:

hello

something)split

done
```

eg. 2

```
input: xyz(abcd)pqr{def}lmn[opq]jkm

output:

xyz

abcd

pqr

def

lmn

opq

jkm
```

My Code :

```
import java.util.*;

class SplitString {

    public static void main(String a[]){

        String str = "hello(something))split)done";
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(str,"(){}[]");
        while(st.hasMoreTokens()){
            System.out.println(st.nextToken());

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *what is your problem?* what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Oops. That python tag should not be there.

Comment: It is working. Not sure what you want to do and what is your problem ?

Comment: Only second one working perfectly, not first one.

Comment: The first example looks weird. To implement it correctly you must first know _why_ the one parenthesis should remain in the output. I cannot see a reason for that.

Comment: Oh you were using StringTokenizer... isn't it something considered to be deprecated and you should switch to String.split() instead?

Comment: if something inside the parenthesis like (xyz) or (xy))z) then i need only inside part of brackets and if there is any other brackets like "))" then only one bracket needs to be consider "xy)z".

Comment: @dineshgaud I tried your code and output of first string is NOT what you quoted.  And, I have no clue on what you are trying to say in your last comment.  It seems you are asking for something else instead of simply string splitting.  Please ask clearly

Comment: In first example I am getting each word separated but this is not I want. The o/p I need is like this one :                                                           "hello

something)split

done"

Comment: it is not a simple string splitting then.  I have no clue why you can expect StringTokenizer to understand your extremely-propietary format and do the splitting for you.  What if the string is `a)(b` or `a(b)c)d)e)f)g` or `a(b}c`?  You are so unclear on your question.  The only suggestion I can give is to write a parser yourself.

Comment: I want o/p only for above two cases. if any two consecutive "(" means escaping, that is "((" is actually output char "(". It's not part of the delimiter. Similar to ")", "{", "}", "[", "]".

Comment: write a little parser to do the work. String splitting cannot do this kind of custom logic.  Just a loop that keep reading, when encounter a open bracket, keep finding a close bracket (and skip escaped close bracket).